# How i can delete some data-attributes with value in file-content?

Tags: php

I want to delete some data-attributes with they values inside the sourcecode of a file.

I load the file inside a variable

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents($pathtofile);
```

Now I want to delete some code, for example
delete `data-myval="something123"`

Important to know is, that the value "something123" is dynamically.

How I can delete all matches of `data-myval="find_all"`

I tried to do it with str_replace and explode failed, it was to complicated and produced too long of code.

Is there a easier way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use a regex to achieve that.

Comment: @Qirel could you show me what you mean

Comment: You can do domething like this: `preg_replace('/data-myval=\"[a-z]*[A-Z]*\"/', '', $input_lines);`. This will look for all data-myval attributes and replace them with nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). This will allow you to match any `regex` expressions and remove the code.

Your regex expression will be (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fW7RjO/2)):

```
data-myval\=\"[^"]+\"
```

Using `preg_replace`:

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents($pathtofile);

$filecontent = preg_replace('/data-myval\=\"[^"]+\"/', '', $filecontent);
```

After this you will need to save the file using `file_put_contents()`.

```
file_put_contents($pathtofile, $filecontent);
```

Comment: great, thanks for explaining me how i can do it - top!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you again

Comment: You missed changing it in the example.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in regex101? just changed now

Comment: No, in the question. You only changed it in the first snippet, not in the second. I fixed it for you :-)